# Divide Pandas dataframe with multiindex by another dataframe with smaller multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide all columns in a dataframe with a multiindex by another dataframe with a multiindex, one level smaller. The first two levels of moth indices are identical. And the third level should be broadcasted.

```
df_0 = pd.DataFrame( {
    "col0": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    "col1": [ 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 ],
} )
df_0.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [ ( "A", "a", 0 ), ( "A", "a", 1 ), ( "A", "b", 0 ), ( "A", "b", 1 ), ( "B", "b", 0 ) ]
)
df_0.index.names = [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame( {
    "stuff": [ 100, 110, 120, 130, ],
} )
df_1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [ ( "A", "a" ), ( "A", "b" ), ( "B", "a" ), ( "B", "b" ) ]
)
df_1.index.names = [ "foo", "bar" ]
print( df_0 )
print( df_1 )
```

This gives me the following two dataframes `df_0`

```
             col0  col1
foo bar baz            
A   a   0       1     3
        1       2     6
    b   0       3     9
        1       4    12
B   b   0       5    15
```

and `df_1`

```
         stuff
foo bar       
A   a      100
    b      110
B   a      120
    b      130
```

If I try to divide each column value by the respective `stuff` column I get an error message

```
print( df_0.div( df_1 ) )
Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous
```

What I want to achieve is the following result:

```
              col0    col1
foo bar baz            
A   a   0    1/100   3/100
        1    2/100   6/100
    b   0    3/110   9/110
        1    4/110  12/110
B   b   0    5/130  15/130
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by first `DataFrame`, so same 3 levels in both, so possible divide by `Series` selected by `stuff`:

```
df = df_0.div(df_1.reindex(df_0.index)['stuff'], axis=0)
print (df)
                 col0      col1
foo bar baz                    
A   a   0    0.010000  0.030000
        1    0.020000  0.060000
    b   0    0.027273  0.081818
        1    0.036364  0.109091
B   b   0    0.038462  0.115385
```

**Details**:

```
print( df_1.reindex(df_0.index)['stuff'] )
foo  bar  baz
A    a    0      100
          1      100
     b    0      110
          1      110
B    b    0      130
Name: stuff, dtype: int64
```

Comment: With Pandas 0.22.0 `df_1.reindex(df_0.index)['stuff']` resulted in a dataframe filled only with `NaN`s. After updating to Pandas 1.0.3 it behaves as expected and shown in the answer.

Comment: @leviathan - Thank you for info. I guess it not working in `0.22.0` because bug.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the dataframes so the indexes are aligned and *then* perform the operations:

```
df = df_0.join(df_1)
df['col0'] = df.col0/df.stuff
df['col1'] = df.col1/df.pop('stuff')

               col0      col1
foo bar baz                    
A   a   0    0.010000  0.030000
        1    0.020000  0.060000
    b   0    0.027273  0.081818
        1    0.036364  0.109091
B   b   0    0.038462  0.115385
```

You might be getting a `NotImplementedError` if your pandas version is outdated. In that case an alternative is to `reset_index` and `merge`:

```
df = df_0.reset_index().merge(df_1, on=['foo', 'bar']).set_index(['foo', 'bar','baz'])
```

Comment: If I try `df_0.join(df_1)` I get the error: "NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented"
I use Pandas version 0.22.0.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have @leviathan ? It works for me on pandas 1.

Comment: I updated Pandas to Version 1.0.3 and now it works.